# QGIS not showing Tigrinya language

Tags: encoding, internationalization, utf-8

I struggle to display Tigrinya language in QGIS. It is supposed to show with UTF-8 encoding. But the letters are not shown, just white spaces.
I went through many other encodings, but coulnd't find one working. When I paste the string in a text editor, it is shown.

This string for example: ኣስመራ Asmara أسمرة
It is Tigrinya, English, Arabic.
But in QGIS I see: "     Asmara أسمرة"

How it looks in QGIS:
[image: Tigrinya not showing]

How it looks in the layer table:

[image: string in layer]

Name in Openstreetmap:

[image: Name in Openstreetmap]

Comment: Possibly a missing font?  Do you have https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Ethiopic and maybe https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+Ethiopic or similar installed?

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I thought it would show in the standard font types. Since the arabic language and others are also shown.

Comment: You can probably make a self-answer out of that.

Answer (score 1):

@BradHards solution worked well: "Possibly a missing font? Do you have fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Ethiopic and maybe fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Serif+Ethiopic or similar installed?"